# Google analytics throw 500 error on specific timerange

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm extracting data from Google Analytics api for a set of profiles. The extract is having the timerange 455daysAgo and until today. I tested the extract both from the C# api and from Google API Explorer. For some reason this specific time range throws a http code 500. To test the boundaries, I tried 456daysAgo to today and 454daysAgo to today. Both of these works as expected and does not fail.

The response from Google Api Explorer

```
500 Internal Server Error

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  117
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Wed, 02 Apr 2014 07:13:04 GMT
expires:  Wed, 02 Apr 2014 07:13:04 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "There was an internal error."
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "There was an internal error."
 }
```

Can anyone guide me to get more detailed error information?

Comment: What dimensions and metrics are you requesting? I wonder if it could be timing out.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your answer until now. I'll try too see the time spent on the response.